# Injecting inline svg with ajax and reloading browser issue

Tags: svg, meteor, iron-router

I'm using the following script to inject a svg in my html body:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    $('body').prepend('<div id="svg"></div>');
    $('#svg').load('images/svg/sprite/sprite.svg');
});
```

This works as intended but things go wrong when I manually reload the page in my browser. But **only** when there's a parameter in my route. When there's no paramater in my route I can refresh all I want without any problems.

```
Router.route('/test') // all OK!
Router.route('/test/:_id') // current template gets rendered multiple times and app finally crashes
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around this. Why is this happening? And how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The load path needs to be absolute.

```
$('#svg').load('/images/svg/sprite/sprite.svg');
```